# Using the Swagger generated API for the Microsoft Cognative Services Recommendations APIs

Tags: swagger

I can't seem to figure out how to include the CSV file content when calling the Swagger API generated methods for the Microsoft Cognitive Services Recommendations API method `Uploadacatalogfiletoamodel(modelID, catalogDisplayName, accountKey);`.  I've tried setting the catalogDisplayName to the full path to the catalog file, however I'm getting:

> "(EXT-0108) Passed argument is invalid."

Any idea how to set the HTTP body content for the Recommendations APIs when making the call?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: To boil it down further; when calling any of the Cog Svcs APIs that require HTTP body content, how do I include the body content when the exposed API doesn't have a parameter for the body?